# Error(36,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET"

Tags: plsql, compiler-errors

Here is my sql script, my friend can run and compile it just fine, but for some reason I cannot. I keep getting the compiler error you see in the title. I ran through it a couple of times and can't seem to find the issue.

```
CREATE or replace procedure ex5b_membership_duration2 is
cursor customer_cursor is           
select customer.customer_id,
CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, 
CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME, 
CUSTOMER.CITY, 
club_membership.club_id,
club_membership.membership_id,
round((sysdate - club_membership.MEMBERSHIP_DATE)/365,2) as time_in_club
from customer
left outer join club_membership 
on customer.customer_id = club_membership.CUSTOMER_ID;
customer_row customer_cursor%rowtype;

begin
dbms_output.put_line('Membership_ID' ||'  '|| 'first_name' ||'   '|| 'last_name' ||'    '|| 'city' ||'     '|| 'club_name' ||'     '|| 'time_in_club');

open customer_cursor;
loop
fetch customer_cursor into customer_row;
exit when customer_cursor%notfound; -- pretty sure its ok till here

if ex5b_check_membership2(customer_row.customer_id) then
dbms_output.put_line(customer_row.membership_id ||'  '|| customer_row.first_name ||'   '|| customer_row.last_name ||'    '|| customer_row.city ||'          '|| ex5b_clubname(customer_row.club_id) ||'     '|| customer_row.time_in_club);

else
dbms_output.put_line('     '|| customer_row.membership_id ||'  '|| customer_row.first_name ||'   '|| customer_row.last_name ||'    '|| customer_row.city ||'            '|| 'No membership yet' );

end if;
end loop;

close customer_cursor;
end;

--Run script
SET serveroutput on;
BEGIN
 EX5B_MEMBERSHIP_DURATION2();

END;
```

Comment: What client you and your friend use to execute the code ? If you're using sqlplus then you're missing `/ ` from the end of the PL/SQL blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing SET SERVEROUTPUT on?

or

Open another sql worksheet, paste the calling block and press f5

```
BEGIN
   EX5B_MEMBERSHIP_DURATION2();
END;
```

or

```
SELECT EX5B_MEMBERSHIP_DURATION2() FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Hmmm, now I'm getting the same error, but now it has a Create quotations instead of set

Comment: are you compiling the calling block together with the function block?

Comment: No, should I be? Sorry I'm not used to this IDE, I generally use sql server

Comment: No its fine.Can you post the error you are getting if you remove set server output on?

Comment: Error(39,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"

Comment: try opening another sql worksheet then paste the calling block then press f5.(assuming you are using oracle sql developer)

Comment: or you can try SELECT EX5B_MEMBERSHIP_DURATION2() FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 1):

The following examples demonstrates the problem and solution with Oracle sqlplus client.

**The problem:**

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.sql
create or replace procedure foo(p_str in varchar2) is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(p_str);
end;

set serveroutput on;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('BING!');
end;


SQL> @/tmp/foo.sql
 10  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.32
GVIMGR@dgvi01.world> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE FOO:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET"
SQL>
```

**The solution:**

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.sql

create or replace procedure foo(p_str in varchar2) is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(p_str);
end;
/
show errors

set serveroutput on;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('BING!');
end;
/

SQL> @/tmp/foo.sql

Procedure created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.39
No errors.
BING!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.11
SQL>
```

In sqlplus you have to end PL/SQL blocks with `/` to execute the block. See also the fine manual: [SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm#SQPUG162).

If you don't do that for the first block then also `set`-command (it's sqlplus command not valid PL/SQL) is added to the buffer. If you now try to execute the block then a valid PL/SQL block is appended with sqlplus command that is not valid PL/SQL - hence the PL/SQL compilation error.

Other clients might behave differently.