# Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a function using oracle, it should be working fine but i keep getting the following error:

> Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET"
> here is my Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CountViewers(nameofPlay plays.play%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER AS
NUM NUMBER;
  BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(registerd) INTO num1 FROM plays WHERE play=nameofPlay;
   return num;
  END;
SET SERVEROUT ON;
DECLARE
inc integer;
res NUMBER;
invalid_status EXCEPTION;
CURSOR clients2 IS SELECT * FROM plays;
name_of_play  plays.play%ROWTYPE;
play_name plays%TYPE;
BEGIN
inc:=0;
name_of_play := '&Play';
OPEN clients2;
LOOP
       FETCH clients2 INTO play_name;
       IF name_of_play != play_name.play and clients2%rowcount>i THEN 
               inc:=inc+1;
       ELSIF name_of_play = play_name.play THEN
               EXIT WHEN clients2%found;
       ELSE
               RAISE invalid_status;
               --like throw error
       END IF;
EXIT WHEN clients2%notfound;
END LOOP;
res:=CountViewers(name_of_play);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name_of_play ||'  | '|| res);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN invalid_status THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The name of play is not found');
END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error(36,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879339/error36-1-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-set)

Comment: Did you write all that code, as a beginner, without trying to execute it even once during the process?!?

Comment: @jarlh where is the problem?!

Comment: @odaiwa - the immediate problem is covered in one of the answers in the linked question: you're missing a slash (/) between the function creation and the rest of the script. ;See [how to run PL/SQL blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663) in the documentation, assuming you're using SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer or SQLcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where do you put this command: `SET SERVEROUT ON;` cause its inside the function declaration.

You should try to take it outside the function:

```sql
SET SERVEROUT ON;
\
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CountViewers(nameofPlay plays.play%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER AS
NUM NUMBER;
  BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(registerd) INTO num1 FROM plays WHERE play=nameofPlay;
   return num;
  END;
DECLARE
inc integer;
res NUMBER;
invalid_status EXCEPTION;
CURSOR clients2 IS SELECT * FROM plays;
name_of_play  plays.play%ROWTYPE;
play_name plays%TYPE;
BEGIN
inc:=0;
name_of_play := '&Play';
OPEN clients2;
LOOP
       FETCH clients2 INTO play_name;
       IF name_of_play != play_name.play and clients2%rowcount>i THEN 
               inc:=inc+1;
       ELSIF name_of_play = play_name.play THEN
               EXIT WHEN clients2%found;
       ELSE
               RAISE invalid_status;
               --like throw error
       END IF;
EXIT WHEN clients2%notfound;
END LOOP;
res:=CountViewers(name_of_play);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name_of_play ||'  | '|| res);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN invalid_status THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The name of play is not found');
END;
```